# Smooth lines using GDI calls

Tags: visual-c++, gdi+, gdi

How to make lines drawn using GDI calls (like polygon(), LineTo()) smooth in Win32? 
Is there any function in GDI or GDI+ that will draw smooth lines ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want this with GDI you will need to do it manually, for GDI+ take a look at [`Graphics::SetSmoothingMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535815%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with one of the `SmoothingModeAntiAlias*` enums.